# SystemVerilog same function, different simulation results

Tags: simulation, system-verilog, rtl

Why does the simulator calculate different results for these signals: **prova1** and **prova2**?  In my opinion, those are representing the very same function.

Signal declaration is:

```
logic [12:0] sub_ton;
logic [11:0] sub_ton_neg;
logic prova1;
logic prova2;
```

[image]

Here are simulation results:
[image]

Comment: Please can you add `sub_ton` to your waveform and how it's driven. And also expand the wave around the relevant part so `sub_ton_neg` is fully visible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the rules for Verilog expression bit length say that operands get extended to their context determined lengths *before* applying the operators. In the expression:

```
~(sub_ton[11:0])+1
```

The `+1` is really `+32'sd1`, a signed 32 bit decimal number. `sub_ton[11:0]` gets 0-padded to 32 bits, then the bitwise negation happens, followed by the addition. When you make the assignment to `sub_ton_neg` it gets truncated back to 12 bits. That truncation doesn't happen in your 3rd assignment to `prova2`.

This little example should give you a better picture of what's happening.

```
module top;
  bit [12:0] sub_ton=1;
  bit [11:0] sub_ton_neg;

  initial begin
    sub_ton_neg = (~(sub_ton[11:0])+1);
    $displayh(sub_ton_neg);
    $displayh((~(sub_ton[11:0])+1));
  end
endmodule
```

The rules are explained section *11.8.2 Steps for evaluating an expression* in the [IEEE SystemVerilog 1800-2017 LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7932212). These rules have been in place since before the IEEE Verilog 1364-1995 LRM.